# VJET With NodeJS Modules

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, vjet

I have just imported a NodeJS project into Eclipse with VJET plugin. It seems nice that it understands some of the NodeJS but I don't like that it doesn't recognize Node-MySQL. Is there any documentation on how to write a project (like NodejsTL) to fill up that missing functionality? I could analyze NodejsTL one but if there is any documentation and tutorial - I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is some documentation on this topic of creating type libraries.

http://www.ebayopensource.org/wiki/display/VJET/VJET+Type+lib+Tutorial+-+part+1

There is some work being proposed to help with this and we are currently looking for help to extend VJET to do this work. Here are the tickets related to this request.

https://www.ebayopensource.org/jira/browse/VJET-87
https://www.ebayopensource.org/jira/browse/VJET-88